# User object returned from Graph API intermittently contains empty array for permissions data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, facebook-oauth

I'm running into a situation where requesting a list of permissions that a user has granted to a canvas application intermittently returns an empty array.

The graph request would look something like this:

https://graph.facebook.com/[uid]?access_token=[token]&fields=permissions

Typically, a normal response would look something like this:

```
"permissions": {
  "data": [
    {
        "installed": 1,
        "email": 1,
        "bookmarked": 1,
        "publish_actions": 1
     }
  ]
}
```

Occasionally though the response looks like this:

```
"permissions": {
  "data": [

  ]
}
```

The code equates this situation to the user having not granted any permissions and restarts the auth flow. The problem appears to be intermittent, because the users eventually make their way into the application and if I manually retry some of the failed requests I find in logs the permissions are returned as expected.

Looking at the User API docs (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/), it looks like permissions that are not granted are excluded. It's not clear from the documentation what happens when no permissions are granted. One would assume an empty map, which would render a response something like:

```
"data": [
  {
  }
]
```

However, even if the response is an empty array, the point in the code where this request is made should not be reachable without accepting a least some permissions.

This leaves me with a few questions that I'm hoping someone with relevant knowledge can answer:

1. Are there any circumstances under which the permissions granted by the user to the application are not available via the Graph API?
2. Are there any circumstances under which a canvas application can be authorized by the user without granting any permissions? (cancelling the auth dialog results in a request with additional query string params, which is handled differently)
3. Are there any circumstances under which a user can revoke initially-granted permissions without de-authorizing the application?

**Edit:**

Based on the discussion below I would like to clarify that my app requires the email permission, which does not appear to be revocable. The app has always required the email permission, so there shouldn't be a case of an older install without that permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Nope, not to my knowledge.
2. That situation is called basic permissions, where no additional permissions are specified in the scope parameter during login
3. Yes, the app user can revoke certain permissions. Go to (http://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications) and click edit on one of the apps (for example Groupon or Music or YouTube) and you can see there's certain permissions that can be removed by the user at any time. So it is good your app reads the permissions it still has available to it.  It might save you some wasted graph calls to objects/actions you're no longer able to get.

Comment: I should have clarified that the app requires email and publish_actions permissions. AFAIK email was always marked as "required" and thus not removable (this is also true of the new auth dialog). So I would expect at least email to always be there. To further clarify, I am making this graph call once a valid user auth token is provided via the signed request, so I would expect the user reaching this point only after authorizing the app and granting the required permissions.

Comment: My answer is still the same. To get email specifically, you have to call the graph: `/me?fields=email` as it is a special case scenario that doesn't come back with a normal /me call.  At least it was that way a month ago...but as you know Facebook is always changing things on us.

Comment: Sorry if this was confusing, but when I mentioned "email", I meant the "email":1 permission entry that is normally returned as part of "permissions". Not the actual email address that one would request with ?fields=email". To reiterate, because I have a user access_token, I would expect the app to be authorized, and thus would expect permissions to always include at least "installed":1 and "email":1. Or am I completely off in this assumption? (Plus there is the special circumstance of it being seemingly intermittent, although I suppose there could be a hole in theflow that I'm not seeing yet)

Comment: My answer is still the same.  You only get the permissions the user grants to you, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: I'm confused -- if the email permission is required by the app, and an auth token is provided only after the user authorizes the app (accepting the email permission), and there is no way to later remove the email permission, how do I have an auth_token without an email permission?

Comment: As I mentioned in my first comment, the email permission does not appear to be removable (although others are). It is not removable for apps authorized with the new auth dialog nor with the old auth dialog.

Comment: You ask "Are there any circumstances under which a user can revoke initially-granted permissions without de-authorizing the application?"  And I answer: "Yes, the app user can revoke certain permissions." The key word is certain, which means some, but not all.  The access token you describe without an email permissions was probably one gotten when your app did not request email permissions. If you think your access token is in error, then log a bug with Facebook at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Fair enough. My questions were general and your answers are correct. I will revise to clarify my special case with the email permission and accept your answer if no one follows up with an answer that addresses my specific situation.